# Deriving a joint cdf from a joint pdf

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I see that a similar question was asked last year, but I am still confused.

I have $f(x,y) = 2e^{-x-y}$,  $ 0 < x < y < \infty $ and need to find the joint CDF.

I have a solution that separates the CDF into 3 cases:

1. For $x<0$ or $y<0,$ $F(x,y) = 0.$ This one is obvious.
2. For $0<y\le x$, $F(x,y) = \ldots$

I managed to solve it with bounds  $0<x<y$ and $0<y<x$. So isn't this the case $y=x$? From what we are given, $y$ can never be equal to $x$. I don't understand how we got this case.

3. For $0<x<y$, $F(x,y) = \ldots$

I can't figure out what the bounds should be. I tried $0<x<y$ and $x<y<\infty$ but it's not working out. Also, isn't "$0<x<y$" true for the entire range? I don't understand how we got this case either.

Can someone please explain why we have the second and third case(why do they need to be separate?), and how to determine what the bounds should be?

Comment: You can use  `\infty` to typeset $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always have $X<Y$. So if $x > y$ then

$$F(x,y)-F(y,y)=\int_y^x \int_{-\infty}^y f(u,v) du dv = \int_y^x \int_{-\infty}^y 0 du dv = 0.$$

In other words, if $x>y$ then $F(x,y)=F(y,y)$. So that reduces the problem to case 3. In case 3 you just have to calculate the integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^y \int_{-\infty}^{\min \{ v,x \}} 2 e^{-u-v} du dv.$$

I got the limits here by rephrasing the region of integration defined as $\{ (u,v) : u \leq x, \, v \leq y, \, u \leq v \}$

Answer (score 0):

If $0<y<x$ then
\begin{align}
F(x,y) = \Pr(X\le x\ \&\ Y\le y) & = \Pr\left(\Big(X\le y\ \&\ Y\le y\Big)\text{ or }\Big(y<X\le x\ \&\ Y\le y\Big)\right) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(X\le y\ \&\ Y\le y)+\underbrace{\Pr(y<X\le x\ \&\ Y\le y)}_{\text{This part is $0$.}}
\end{align}
The c.d.f. is perfectly well defined in the case where $0<y<x$, just as it is well defined (and equal to $0$) if $x=y=-1$.

Comment: This does not help me understand at all... Why bother posting anything if you're not even going to try?

Comment: @Bob : If this isn't good enough for you, then you need to try harder.  I was very careful in writing this, but I had to do a certain amount of guessing to figure out what you wanted to know.

Comment: I think I asked some very specific questions that were not addressed. I still don't undersand how the CDF can be defined by something other than 0 when 0<y<x. According to what we are given, 0<x<y ... So how can y be less than x?

Comment: How it can be something other than $0$ when $0<y<x$ is just what my answer explains.  I wrote the probability as a sum of two terms, one of which is $0$ precisely because $y<x$, and the other is positive.