# CDF from joint PDF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

My joint PDF function of (x,y) is given 
\begin{cases} 2e^{-x-y}, & 0\leq x\leq y\leq \infty\\0, & otherwise
\end{cases}
How do I find joint CDF from this PDF? I know that my CDF is zero when both x and y are less then zero and that I'm supposed to integrate PDF on a given region, but there is a solution in my book that says I'm supposed to calculate CDF on this area too:

$$ 0\leq y\leq x, y>0  $$

and it equals $$e^{-2y} - 1$$

Why do I do this? Shouldn't CDF be zero in this case? Also, isn't it redudant to say that y>0 in that area?

Comment: Since you rollbacked the edit, why do you think $0\le x\le-\infty$ is possible?

Comment: sorry, my bad, i don't how that minus sign ended up there

Comment: Saying $0\leq y\leq x, y>0$ does have duplication, but it seems harmless.  You do need a zero bound on $y$ as the result would be different if you were considering $y \le x, y \lt 0$

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123801

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is the *cumulative* distribution function so $F(x,y)=\mathbb P(X\le x, Y \le y)$ is an increasing function of $x$ and of $y$

So when $0 \le y \le x$ you have

- $\mathbb P(X\le x, Y \le y) = \mathbb P( X\le y, Y \le y) + \mathbb P( y \lt X\le x, Y \le y)$
- where you can find $\mathbb P( X\le y, Y \le y)$ from your previous calculations for the CDF
- while $\mathbb P( y \lt X\le x, Y \le y) = 0$ since the density is zero in this region